# Can argv** be returned as a function return value

Tags: pointers, return-value

In C we should return pointer variable if define as 1- static stack 2- Heap-allocated 3-const address.

The question is:

Can  argv** variable  in main function be returned as a function return value without undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine a situation which requires to return argv** from a function, but you get it from `main (int argc, char* argv[])` so yes. You can pass it as a parameter to a function and return it to another function. They're like const for you.

You can't return pointer to the data allocated temporarily for the function's own needs. `int* F{ int A; return &A; }` will not work. But you can set `int* A=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` and `return A;`: it'll be your tiny wrapper around the malloc function. You can even receive `int* A` as a parameter and `return A+1;` the rule you mentioned in the beginning actually means "there are some restrictions of allocation methods if you're planning to use the pointer after the function exits". You can break the rule without returning the value (for example, you can store the poiner in a global variable and it'll become invalid when the function exits, like `void F{ int A; GlobPtr=&A; }` which will cause the same problems).

But your function does not allocate argv, it's allocated before your code starts. So you can even shift it by one value as you extract parameters one-by-one, the returned pointer *nextargv[] will also point to valid memory area.